# How to get comboBox value?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, jframe

My code looks like this :

```
private void populateRoleNameComboBox() {
    roleNameJComboBox.removeAllItems();
    roleNameJComboBox.addItem(UserAccountDirectory.ADMIN_ROLE);
    roleNameJComboBox.addItem(UserAccountDirectory.SALESPERSON_ROLE);
    roleNameJComboBox.addItem(UserAccountDirectory.SUPPLIER_ROLE);   
    roleNameJComboBox.addItem(UserAccountDirectory.CUSTOMER_ROLE);
   //populatePersonNameComboBox();
}


private void populatePersonNameComboBox() {
        personNameJComboBox.removeAllItems();

       if(roleNameJComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(UserAccountDirectory.SUPPLIER_ROLE)){
        for(Supplier s : supplierDirectory.getSupplierList()){
            personNameJComboBox.addItem(s);
                    }
               }
        else if(roleNameJComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(UserAccountDirectory.SALESPERSON_ROLE)){
            for(Person p : employeeDirectory.getSalesPersonList()){
                personNameJComboBox.addItem(p);
                    }
               }
            else if(roleNameJComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(UserAccountDirectory.CUSTOMER_ROLE)){
            for(Person person : customerDirectory.getCustomerList()){
                personNameJComboBox.addItem(person);
                    }
              }
  }
```

My personNameJComboBox showing no values. How can I implement the logic to get values for 2nd comboBox based on 1st one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example to get your started. Basically you need to change the model of the second combo box whenever the selected item of the first combo box changes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JComboBox mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox subComboBox;
    private Hashtable subItems = new Hashtable();

    public ComboBoxTwo()
    {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox( items );
        mainComboBox.addActionListener( this );

        //  prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        getContentPane().add( mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST );

        //  Create sub combo box with multiple models

        subComboBox = new JComboBox();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        getContentPane().add( subComboBox, BorderLayout.EAST );

        String[] subItems1 = { "Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

        String[] subItems2 = { "Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

        String[] subItems3 = { "Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
//      mainComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = (String)mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get( item );

        if (o == null)
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTwo();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `JComboBox` associates with a `DefaultComboBoxModel` by default to add item or manage state change of items. However If you want to add/remove an item to a `JComboBox` you must use an implementation of `MutableComboboxModel` and `DefaultComboBoxModel` implements `MutableComboBoxModel` too.

I don't see any reason that your `personNameJComboBox.addItem(item)` won't work, *unless you are trying to populate data with out listening to an action event  of `roleNameJComboBox` for which at least on item will be selected.* Make sure that you are using an `ActionListener` with `roleNameJcomboBox` and implements `actionPerformed()` function in which you should call the `populatePersonNameComboBox()` function.